# What is the difference between SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler and Batch-Apex

Tags: batch, api-25

We're working on an organisation with quita a few batch processes. Monitoring some of the batch operations in testing I noticed that under the Operation column, there are both `SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler` and `Batch Apex`.

A batch process that I'm working on runs as `Batch Apex` in a full sandbox, but runs as `SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler` in the production organisation.

[image: batch apex vs SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler]

I fail to find (may be depended on my search capabilities) any explanation to the difference in the documentation. Can any of you feed my hunger for knowledge ?

Comment: Is it possible to restrict logs to generate such cases?

Answer (score 2):

If you process 1000 records these will be processed in 5 chunks of 200 records. For each chunck you will see a SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler (corresponds to the execute method in the batch).

Comment: That is also the case for the rows showing Batch Apex. What is the difference and why does the batch process giving SerialBatchApex... in production Batch Apex in sandbox ?